How can I fix Engine.IO ping timeouts when writing large amounts of data over Socket.IO?
I'm working on an IOT device running a bespoke Socket.IO(SIO) client connecting to a node.js Socket.IO server on Linux. At initial connection, the server sends the client ~100KB of data, but after that throughput drops to a couple <20B packets every 1-3 seconds. However, when the customer network or anything in between them and us slows down for a bit during the initial ~100KB download, too often the server gets an Engine.IO(EIO) timeout and sends the client a connection-close before the client can finish downloading the events sent at initial connection.
Over the air, we see the following:

TCP handshake, TLS setup, WebSocket Upgrade
Server->Client EIO CONNECT
Client->Server SIO CONNECT
Server->Client: EIO PING
Client->Server: EIO PONG
Server->Client: About 60 packets SIO Events, about 100KB, takes > EIO pingTimeout
Server->Client: EIO PING
Server->Client: EIO CLOSE
WebSocket/TLS/TCP teardown

From the server's perspective, it emit()'d all 100KB near instantly, then after pingInterval, sent another PING, and didn't hear the PONG back in time so it sent CLOSE. In this case, the TCP connection was still up, just slow, so the PING didn't make it to the device in time because the tube was clogged with the initial data download.
I assumed this was due to buffering at some layer, but limiting tcp_wmem, wmem_max, wmem_default did not help. It's likely the server's NIC is doing TCP offload but I can't tell currently.
Is there a way we can limit Socket.IO's emit()s to reflect the actual throughput of the connection, so that Engine.IO PINGs can be queued for transmit in a reasonable amount of time? Currently, it looks like we'll need to set EIO pingTimeout according to the worst-case queueing / worst-case customer internet speed + some headroom. If we could limit the max queued Socket.IO data to something like 2 packets before allowing EIO to send a PING, this would be a lot more manageable. Or, am I going about it the wrong way - is there a better way to handle this? Maybe with Socket.IO acknowledgements for the initial events?
